# Why would my program throw a python attribute error?

Tags: python, a-star

Python newbie here attempting to write an A* search algorithm for the pancake search algorithm. However, my constructor is throwing a 'Pancakes' object has no attribute 'numPancakes' in some functions but not the others that also use it. What is going wrong?
The print function below does not throw problems.

```
class Pancakes:
    def __init__(self, stack, backwardCost): 
        print("Constructor called")
        self.backwardCost = backwardCost
        self.forwardCost = self.calculateForwardCost()
        self.numPancakes = len(stack) - 1
        self.pancakeStack = stack
        self.total =  self.calculateForwardCost() + self.backwardCost



def print(self):
    stackState = "Stack: "
    for i in range((self.numPancakes)):
        stackState += str(self.pancakeStack[i]) + " "
    print(stackState)
```

As soon as I try to use

```
def calculateForwardCost(self):
    forwardCost = 0
    for i in range(self.numPancakes):
        gap = self.pancakeStack[index] - self.pancakeStack[index + 1]
        if gap < -1 or gap > 1:
            forwardCost += 1
    return forwardCost
```

the program says

```
File "aStar.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.forwardCost = self.calculateForwardCost()
  File "aStar.py", line 22, in calculateForwardCost
    for i in range(self.numPancakes):
AttributeError: 'Pancakes' object has no attribute 'numPancakes'
```

Comment: you call the `calculateForwardCost()` function before you have set `numPancakes`

Comment: Before you call the function you should create a Pancakes object. myObj = Pancakes(stack, backwardCost). Then print myObj for testing. Then call calculateForwardCost.

Comment: Btw you want probably 'i' instead of 'index' in the line with 'gap' ;)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the order that you have things in the constructor:

```
self.forwardCost = self.calculateForwardCost()  # Requires self.numPancakes

self.numPancakes = len(stack) - 1  # But self.numPancakes isn't set until here
```

You're attempting to use `self.numPancakes` before it's assigned. Just swap those lines to make sure `numPancakes` is set first:

```
self.numPancakes = len(stack) - 1

self.forwardCost = self.calculateForwardCost()
```

---

Actually, I'm reading over your code again, and `pancakeStack` is also being used before its assigned. Every attribute needed inside of `calculateForwardCost` needs to be assigned before that function is called.